# ¿Cuál es el sitio adecuado para definir funciones personalizadas en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hay una serie de funciones que suelo crear de forma habitual en mis proyectos, algunas de ellas son funciones de debug propias (utilizo microtimes, var_dumps, print_r,...) para formatear los datos a mi gusto, y otras son funciones que acaban siendo utilizadas muy a menudo en el proyecto en cuestión (por ejemplo funciones que hagan determinadas cosas con variables de sesión, que "mastiquen" un objeto/array y lo devuelvan de una forma determinada, etc..).

Siempre tengo dudas acerca de dónde debería englobar estas funciones. Hasta ahora el segundo tipo de funciones (trabajo con variables de sesión, funciones de ambito general que alteren variables del proyecto) las ponía en un controlador (CommonController), mientras que el primer tipo de funciones (funciones de debug en su gran mayoría) las pensaba poner en un helper.

No obstante, sigo teniendo serias dudas acerca de si ambos grupos de funciones deberían ser colocados en esos sitios.

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta casi que se basa en opiniones, sin embargo, hay ciertas convenciones que suelen usarse en Laravel, entre ellas el uso de helpers:

1. En cuanto al primer tipo de funciones: Si son funciones genéricas, que potencialmente vas a usar a menudo, y cuya funcionalidad es pequeña pero útil, y no está relacionada con otras tantas que puedas tener o ya existir, entonces **los helpers son una buena idea**. ¿Cómo o dónde ponerlo? eso ya se basa en opiniones, depende si quieres mantener tu directorio app totalmente PSR-4 o no.
2. El segundo tipo de funciones parece tener varias soluciones posibles, dependiendo realmente del enfoque y de su contexto de uso y utilidad:

   - Yo contemplaría la posibilidad de crear un servicio, si el trabajo que hacen es extenso y/o complejo, de esta forma podrían escalarse mejor a futuro, para que funcionen como una caja negra, y que no estén tan acoplados ni sean dependientes de la estructura de controladores.
   - Los helpers de nuevo son una opción, si algunas de esas funciones tan solo reducen algunos procesos típicos y pequeños.
   - El controlador base es otra opción (tal y como lo usas ahora), pero esto suele malinterpretarse: Este controlador base (que ya existe en app/Controllers/Controller.php) debería utilizarse para labores que potencialmente se vayan a ejecutar en (casi) cada llamada a un método de un controlador cualquiera. No necesariamente es un repositorio de algunas labores que aparentemente son útiles o comunes.
   - Hay otras opciones como jobs, middlewares, sesiones, eventos, que también pueden ser soluciones, sin embargo habría que revisar detalladamente cada caso.